# Is it possible to use dynamic object key with v-model?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-model

This is my data structure:

```js
form: {
   email: '',
   password: ''
}
```

Now I want to use a loop and set the model dynamically with the `form` object.

```js
<div class="my-1" v-for="(value,name, index) in form">
   <p class="capitalize"> {{ value }} </p>
   <!--<custom-input :value="value"></custom-input>-->
   <t-input v-model="dynamickmodel" class="w-full"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using a reference to the object and its key:

```html
<t-input v-model="form[name]" class="w-full"/>
```

Changes to `t-input` should update the value for that key.

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="my-1" v-for="(value, name, index) in form">
    <p class="capitalize"> {{ value }} </p>
    <input v-model="form[name]" class="w-full"/>
  </div>
</div>
```